# What can I do if I note closevotes on a perfectly good question but have no access to the reopen / close queues?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

What can I do, if I note that perfectly good questions are closevoted but still open, and I dont have access to the reopen / close queues? Having access to these higher rep review queues, I could simply review it and say "leave open". But what can people do who have not enough rep for this?

Out of my head I see just the following possible things one could do:

1. "Flag the question to leave open" explaing why I think it is a good and legitimate question which should not be closed.
2. Explain in a comment below the question explaining why it should not get closed
3. Start a chat or mete discussion, which might however be a bit premature if the question is still open.

What do other people think what lower rep users can do best in this case, to state the opinion that the question should be left open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing.

If the question is actually a perfectly good question, the chances are high that the close votes will decay and it won't be closed. Any action would be premature in this case.

If the question is actually closed, you have all the usual tools from flags, reopen votes to meta posts at your disposal.

Now, if the question is fundamendally a good question, but maybe written in an unfortunate or easily misunderstood way, editing it to make it clearer can help a lot with preventing any further close votes.

A flag is not really appropriate as moderators can only reset close votes by using the very ugly workaround of closing and immediately reopening a question.

Comment: Editing for clarity is often a good idea; even if you *personally* don't find it terribly unclear, if others have and still others might that's good enough reason to clarify preemptively. Flagging is also a good idea for closures that might have negative effects otherwise, for instance migrations (which can't be re-opened without moderator assistance).

Comment: @Shog9 This site doesn't have any migration targets, so the danger of bad migrations by the community doesn't apply. But of course trying to prevent a bad migration would be a reason to flag.